# Как реализовать вывод на страницу картинки из базы данных sqlite Flask?

Tags: flask

В проеке на Flask из базы данных sqlite необходимо вывести картинку. В таблице sqlite поле foto varchar(20). В нем указываю путь к картинке /static/img/car.svg и тогда запись вместе с остальными записями из полей таблицы выводится. Код app.py и create.html приведен ниже. Но как вывести картинку, если в поле foto задав просто car.svg, а не /static/img/car.svg?
Вывод картинки:`<img class="header__img" src={{post.foto}} alt="car">`

```
Содержимое app.py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///new.db'
#app.config['STATIC_FOLDER'] = '/static/img/' 
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(300), nullable=False)
    text = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    foto = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)

@app.route('/index')
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/posts')
def posts():
    posts = Post.query.all()
    return render_template('posts.html', posts = posts)

@app.route('/create', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def create():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        title = request.form['title']
        text = request.form['text']
        foto = request.form['foto']
        post = Post(title = title, text = text, foto = foto)
        try:
            db.session.add(post)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect('/')
        except:
            return "При добавлении статьи произошла ошибка!"  
    else:
        return render_template('create.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

```
Содержимое posts.html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{%  block title %}
Все записи
{% endblock %}

{%  block content %}
<h1>Ноутбуки</h1>
<div class="row">
   {% for post in posts %}
   <div class="feature col">
    <div class="feature-icon bg-primary bg-gradient">
      <svg class="bi" width="1em" height="1em"><use xlink:href="#collection"></use></svg>
    </div>
    <h2>{{post.title}}</h2>
    <p>{{post.text}}</p>
    <p>{{post.foto}}</p> 
    
    <!-- <img class="header__img" src='/static/img/car.svg' alt="car"> -->
    <img class="header__img" src={{post.foto}} alt="car"> 
    <a href="#" class="icon-link">
      Читать далее
      <svg class="bi" width="1em" height="1em"><use xlink:href="#chevron-right"></use></svg>
    </a>
  </div>
   {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```